# Launching Visual Studio Code shows a black screen

Tags: lubuntu, visual-studio-code

When I launched Visual Studio Code on my Ubuntu this screen showed

[image]

Comment: Please look at your vscode error logs `~/.config/Code/logs` for clues! When in there use this command to find the latest entry `ls -t | head -n 1`!

Comment: What I need to do after found latest entry?

Comment: Look for error messages! If any!

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: I dont see any error message just some number and I dont know what it is

Comment: I've tried to reinstall it a several time but still the same